# What is the significance of rasterize paint extending over multiple frames

Tags: performance, profiling, google-chrome-devtools, paint

I have started looking into the client side performance of my app using Chrome's Timeline tools. However, whilst I have found many articles on how to use them, information on how to interpret the results is more sparse and often vague.

Currently I am looking at scroll performance and attempting to hit 60FPS.

This screenshot show's the results of my most recent timeline recording.
As can be seen most frames are over 60 FPS and several are over 30 FPS.

[image]

If I zoom in on one particular frame - the one with duration 67.076ms I can see a few things:

1. the duration of the frame is 67ms, but aggregated time is 204ms
2. 201ms of this time is spent painting BUT the two paint events in
   this frame are of duration 1.327 ms and 0.106 ms
3. The total duration for the JS event, update layer tree and paint events is
   only 2.4 ms
4. There is a long green hollow bar (rasterize Paint)
   which lasts the duration of the frame and in fact starts before and
   continues after it.

I have a few questions on this:

1. the aggregated time is far longer than the frame time - is it
   correct to assume that these are parrallel processes?
2. the paint time for the frame (204ms) far exceeds the time for the two paint events (1.433ms) - is this because it includes the
   rasterize paint events
3. why does the rasterize paint event span multiple frames?
4. where would one start optimizing this?
5. Finally can someone point me to some good resources on understanding this?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat unfortunate result of the way the 'classic' waterfall Timeline view coalesces multiple events. If you expand that long "Rasterize Paint" event, you'll see a bunch of individual events, which are going to be somewhat shorter. You may really want to switch to Flame Chart mode for troubleshooting rendering performance, where the rasterize events are shown on appropriate threads.

Comment: what is "Flame Chart mode" ?